# How to get user points from Stream Elements

Tags: api, processing

I am currently working on an application in processing where i plan to utilise the stream elements point system as a currency in my game. how do I get the information from stream elements into my program ?

I have looked at the API documentation and found a section for points called "get" but there is no associated html address for me to query.

Edit:
For reference, stream elements is a twitch bot Which has the ability to store a list of “points” that users have earnt from doing certain actions on stream such as watching over a period of time.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What exactly is the stream elements point system?

Comment: My apologise, I have edited my original post to explain what stream Elements is